# Alice plays a game of choosing numbers and replacing them with some other.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, invariance

> The following $100$ numbers are written on the board:$$2^1 - 1, 2^2 - 1, 2^3 - 1, \dots, 2^{100} - 1.$$
> Alice chooses two numbers $a,b,$ erases them and writes the number $\dfrac{ab - 1}{a+b+2}$ on the board. She keeps doing this until a single number remains on the board. If the sum of all possible numbers she can end up with is $\dfrac{p}{q}$ where $p, q$ are coprime, then what
> is the value of $\log_{2}(p+q)$?

---

Since many of these types of questions uses invariants, I was trying to find an invariant. But I'm unable to find it. I would like someone to provide hints.

Comment: I suggest working this for smaller numbers than $100$.  Try to find a workable pattern.

Answer (score 3):

If we let $a_i$ be the numbers left on the board at any stage, then $$\Delta=\sum\limits_{i}\frac{1}{a_i+1}$$ is invariant.

Note that if $a,b$ are replaced at a stage by $\frac{ab-1}{a+b+2}$, then $\frac1{a+1}+\frac1{b+1}$ is changed to $\frac{1}{\frac{ab-1}{a+b+2}+1}=\frac1{\frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{a+b+2}}=\frac1{a+1}+\frac1{b+1}$.

What is this sum $\Delta$? It is equal to $\frac{2^{100}-1}{2^{100}}$, because it is invariant under this process and therefore, it shouldn't have changed from what we started with.

If the last no. on the board is $L$, then $$\Delta=\frac1{L+1}=\frac{2^{100}-1}{2^{100}}$$

$$\implies L=\frac{1}{2^{100}-1}=\frac p q.$$

We need $\mathrm{log}_2(p+q)$ which is $100$.

---

I noticed that applying $\frac{ab-1}{a+b+2}$ to $a=2^i-1,b=2^j-1$ always managed to clear the $-1$s and left me with a perfect power of $2$. So, I figured there had to be something involving $a+1,b+1$. So, I wrote the $\frac{ab-1}{a+b+2}$ as $\frac{ab-1}{(a+1)+(b+1)}$.

I also noticed that $ab-1=(a+1)(b+1)-((a+1)+(b+1))$. Using this, I wrote $\frac{ab-1}{a+b+2}+1=\frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{(a+1)+(b+1)}=\frac{1}{\frac{(a+1)+(b+1)}{(a+1)(b+1)}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a+1}+\frac 1{b+1}}$.

I wrote $\frac{ab-1}{a+b+2}+1=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{ab-1}{a+b+2}+1}}$ and I knew I had the invariant. I guessed the $\Delta$ with this.

Comment: Hello. I tried your invarient not just with those numbers given in the problem, but also with some other numbers, like 1,2,3,4. And it seems, after applying the $\frac{ab-1}{a+b+2}$ algorithm, it looks like it still holds! Does that mean the invarient is connected to/constructed upon $\frac{ab-1}{a+b+2}$? If so, how did you construct this invarient? What was your approach? I will be grateful if you please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I will edit my answer to include some motivation for my choice.

Comment: Thank you. Also please mention if you used any technique to "construct" the invarient, as many problems use this similar type of concept, where this knowledge can be used.

Comment: Like you said, you want the invariant $f(a) + f(b) = f((ab-1)/(a+b+2))$. You can try to come up with various transformations to simplify it. For example, looking at the denominator $a+b+2$, we might think of setting $ c = a+1, b = d+1$, to get $ f(c-1) + f(d-1) = f( (cd-c-d)    / (c+d) ) $. Letting $f(n-1) = g(n)$, we get $ g(c) + g(d) = g( cd / (c+d) )$. From here, recognize that $ g(n) = k/n$ is the family of solutions. Substitute this back to get $f(n) = k/(n+1)$.